# программа не ждет загрузки службы

Tags: java, android

Как исправить в программе такой недочет что служба загружается после того как закончится загрузка `onCreate`?

Код стандарт из примеров, я создаю

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, UCache.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Вернее запускаю службу, и она запускается не сразу после этих двух действий, а когда закончится событие `OnCreat` как такое может быть? Я получаю как бы ошибку на строчке `bindService`, но приложение продолжает работать...

Ошибка

> 08-06 13:34:47.144  13419-13419/ux.uchat E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity
>   ux.uchat.Start_UChat has leaked ServiceConnection
>   ux.uchat.Start_UChat$1@4119fef8 that was originally bound here
>       android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity ux.uchat.Start_UChat has leaked ServiceConnection ux.uchat.Start_UChat$1@4119fef8 that was
>   originally bound here
>               at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:999)
>               at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:893) at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1490)
>               at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1479)
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
>               at ux.uchat.Start_UChat.onCreate(Start_UChat.java:55)

Comment: Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). А пока что можно только гадать, в чем там проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение что Вы привели, не ошибка запуска службы, а предупреждение о возможной утечке памяти. В имплементации ServiceConnection есть ссылка на активити Start_UChat или что-то в этом роде.

Теперь по запуску службы. Вы не можете ее запустить вручную в прямом смысле слова. Вы сообщаете системе что хотите ее запустить, а система как только освободится UI thread, т.е. после окончания onCreate(), запустит службу используя этот-же UI thread.

Comment: А, понятно, я разобрался как обойтись без службы, спасибо...